# Windows Search shared folder

Tags: .net, windows, search, directory, shared

Hiho,

i'm using the windows search to search some files with my program.

The query looks like this:

```
"SELECT [Rows, e.g. System.FileName] FROM Systemindex WHERE scope='" & uri & "' AND FREETEXT('[Filename]')"
```

The variable uri looks like this:

```
Dim uri As String = New Uri("\\PCName\Searchtest").AbsoluteUri
```

`\\PCName\Searchtest` is the path to the folder that I shared in the network (the same PC where I search).

When I use it on a normal folder, e.g. `C:/Searchtest`, everything works, but it won't work with my shared folder. Does anyone know why? The "normal" windows search finds my files there.

And i have one question more:
I've wrote a .osdx file to see my search results through the windows explorer (my program is a RESTful service), but when I get a result, I get the message (translated, probably not 100% correct): "This element was blocked because of your internet security settings."
I found 2 or 3 people who have/had the same error, but I never found a solution. I tried to change the internet security settings in the internet and intranet area, but it didn't change anything.

Strange exception to this problem: I have a .pdf file in the folder, which is tagged as "file from a different computer".  This is shown fine and doesn't have this internet security error. If i click on "allow" in the options of the file, I get the internet security error again.

Comment: What is the content of `uri` after the `AbsoluteUri` formatting?

Comment: The uri is "file://PCName/Searchtest"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. It was more a problem in my head than a real problem.
The files are obviously in my local folder, e.g. C:/Searhctest, and not in the folder \PCName\Searchtest.